# Canvas loading animation - follow-up

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

This is kind of a follow-on from here:

[Canvas animation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58788/canvas-animation)

I've been trying to copy the following GIF animation using a canvas.

[image]

I have re-factored the code following Stuart's [pointers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58788/canvas-animation#answer-58829) and wanted to know if I was doing what I should be.

<kbd>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qalepoli/1/edit)</kbd>

```
/*Start Canvas*/

var Canvas = function(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.segments = {};
    this.outerSegments = {};
    this.percentage = 0;
};

Canvas.prototype.render = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.clear();
    this.arcFrame({
        start: 0,
        stop: 360,
        fillStyle: 'white',
        radius: 105,
        frameWidth: 15,
        frameStart: 0,
        frameStop: 360
    });
    this.circle({
        fill: true,
        fillStyle: 'white',
        stroke: true,
        strokeStyle: 'lightgrey',
        radius: 20
    });
    this.circle({
        fill: true,
        fillStyle: this.circleGradient({
            radiusStart: 60,
            radiusFinish: 1,
            colourStart: 'white',
            colourFinish: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
        }),
        radius: 60
    });
    this.renderPercentage(this.percentage, {
        fillStyle: 'green',
        font: '16pt Arial',
        textAlign: 'center',
        x: this.canvas.width / 2,
        y: this.canvas.height / 2 + 8
    });
    for (var percentage in this.segments) {
        var segment = this.segments[percentage];

        if (segment.options.distanceFromCenter < 15) {
            segment.update('distanceFromCenter', segment.options.distanceFromCenter + 0.3);
        }
        if (segment.options.broke === true) {
            if (segment.options.height < 105) {
                segment.update('height', segment.options.height + 3);
            } else if (segment.options.height >= 105) {
                segment.update('height', 105);
                this.outerSegments[percentage].update('started', true);
            } else {
                segment.update('distanceFromCenter', segment.options.distanceFromCenter - 0.1);
            }
        }
        this.renderSegment(segment);
    }
    if (typeof this.segments[100] !== "undefined") {
        if (this.segments[100].options.distanceFromCenter >= 15) {
            this.segments[100].update('broke', true);
        }
    }
    for (var percentage in this.outerSegments) {
        var segment = this.outerSegments[percentage];
        if (segment.options.started === true) {
            if (segment.options.outerAnimThickness >= 0) {
                segment.update('outerAnimThickness', segment.options.outerAnimThickness - 0.2);
            } else {
                segment.update('outerAnimDistance', 200);
                segment.update('finished', true);
            }
            if (segment.options.outerAnimDistance < 40) {
                segment.update('outerAnimDistance', segment.options.outerAnimDistance + 0.5)
            }
            this.renderOuterAnim(segment);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        self.render();
    });
};

Canvas.prototype.circle = function(options) {
    options.start = 0;
    options.stop = 360;
    this.arc(options);
};

Canvas.prototype.arcFrame = function(options) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(
        this.canvas.width / 2,
        this.canvas.height / 2,
        options.radius,
        Helper.toRadians(options.start),
        Helper.toRadians(options.stop),
        false
    );
    if (options.fillStyle) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = options.fillStyle;
    }
    this.ctx.arc(
        this.canvas.width / 2,
        this.canvas.height / 2,
        options.radius + options.frameWidth,
        Helper.toRadians(options.frameStart),
        Helper.toRadians(options.frameStop),
        true
    );
    this.ctx.fill();
};

Canvas.prototype.arc = function(options) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    if (options.lineWidth) {
        this.ctx.lineWidth = options.lineWidth;
    }
    this.ctx.arc(
        this.canvas.width / 2,
        this.canvas.height / 2,
        options.radius,
        Helper.toRadians(options.start),
        Helper.toRadians(options.stop),
        options.antiClockwise || false
    );
    if (options.stroke) {
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = options.strokeStyle || 'white';
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }
    if (options.fillStyle) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = options.fillStyle;
    }
    if (options.fill) {
        this.ctx.fill();
    }
};

Canvas.prototype.renderSegment = function(segment) {
    this.arcFrame({
        start: Math.floor(segment.lastPercentage * 3.6),
        stop: Math.ceil(segment.percentage * 3.6),
        fillStyle: 'green',
        radius: segment.options.height,
        frameWidth: segment.options.distanceFromCenter,
        frameStart: Math.ceil(segment.percentage * 3.6),
        frameStop: Math.floor(segment.lastPercentage * 3.6)
    });
};

Canvas.prototype.renderOuterAnim = function(segment) {
    this.arcFrame({
        start: Math.floor(segment.lastPercentage * 3.6),
        stop: Math.ceil(segment.percentage * 3.6),
        fillStyle: 'green',
        radius: 105 + segment.options.outerAnimDistance,
        frameWidth: segment.options.outerAnimThickness,
        frameStart: Math.ceil(segment.percentage * 3.6),
        frameStop: Math.floor(segment.lastPercentage * 3.6)
    });
};

Canvas.prototype.renderPercentage = function(percentage, options) {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = options.fillStyle;
    this.ctx.font = options.font;
    this.ctx.textAlign = options.textAlign;
    this.ctx.fillText(percentage, options.x, options.y);
};

Canvas.prototype.clear = function() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
};

Canvas.prototype.circleGradient = function(options) {
    var gradient = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
        this.canvas.width / 2,
        this.canvas.height / 2,
        options.radiusStart,
        this.canvas.width / 2,
        this.canvas.height / 2,
        options.radiusFinish
    );
    gradient.addColorStop(0, options.colourFinish);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, options.colourStart);
    return gradient;
};

/*Finish Canvas*/

/*Start Segment*/
var Segment = function(percentage, lastPercentage, options) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
    this.lastPercentage = lastPercentage;
    this.options = options || {
        height: 20,
        distanceFromCenter: 0,
        broke: false,
        finished: false
    };
    return this;
};

Segment.prototype.update = function(key, value) {
    if (typeof this.options[key] !== "undefined") {
        this.options[key] = value;
    }
};

var OuterSegment = function(percentage, lastPercentage, options) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
    this.lastPercentage = lastPercentage;
    this.options = options || {
        started: false,
        outerAnimThickness: 5,
        outerAnimDistance: 15,
        colour: 'green'
    }
    return this;
}

OuterSegment.prototype.update = function(key, value) {
    if (typeof this.options[key] !== "undefined") {
        this.options[key] = value;
    }
}
/*Finish Segment*/

/*Start Loader*/
var Loader = function(options) {
    this.options = options || {
        loader: 'loader',
        colour: 'green'
    };
    this.start();
};

Loader.prototype.setPercentage = function(percentage) {
    if (typeof percentage === "undefined") {
        return percentage;
    } else {
        if (percentage > 100) {
            return false;
        }
        this.lastPercentage = this.percentage;
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.canvas.percentage = this.percentage;
        this.canvas.segments[percentage] = new Segment(percentage, this.lastPercentage);
        if (percentage === 100 && typeof this.canvas.segments[100] !== "undefined") {
            this.canvas.outerSegments[100] = new OuterSegment(100, 0);
        } else {
            this.canvas.outerSegments[percentage] = new OuterSegment(percentage, this.lastPercentage);
        }
        if (typeof this.canvas.segments[this.lastPercentage] !== "undefined") {
            this.canvas.segments[this.lastPercentage].update('broke', true);
        }
    }
};

Loader.prototype.addPercentage = function(percentage) {
    percentage = this.percentage + percentage > 100 ? 100 : this.percentage + percentage;
    this.setPercentage(percentage);
};

Loader.prototype.start = function(remove) {
    if (typeof remove !== "undefined") {
        document.getElementById('canvas').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('canvas'));
    }
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', 300);
    canvas.setAttribute('width', 300);
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
    this.options.loader.appendChild(canvas);
    this.canvas = new Canvas(document.getElementById('canvas'));
    this.canvas.render();
    this.percentage = 0;
};

Loader.prototype.reset = function() {
    for (var key in this.canvas.segments) {
        delete this.canvas.segments[key];
        this.canvas.segments = {};
    }
    this.canvas.percentage = 0;
    this.percentage = 0;
    this.lastPercentage = false;
}
/*Finish Loader*/

/*Start Helper*/
var Helper = {
    toRadians: function(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }
};
/*Finish Helper*/
```

Comment: There are a lot of if-elseif-elses in the code. Maybe you can use more sub-functions to get better readable code?

Comment: Everything can be modularised later, I just wanted to know if I was using everything correctly and if certain parts can be simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several valid ways of doing this, but the code still seems a bit convoluted to me.

1. a lot of the work of controlling the size and shape of the segments is within the `Canvas` prototype, which I would expect (from its name) to be exclusively concerned with drawing.
2. `Segment.update` simply sets a property and so does not add much value. It would be better if the `update` methods actually did all the work of changing the shape and size of the segment in each frame.
3. As it stands, `Segment` and `OuterSegment` are nearly identical so there's not much point in having both. This would be different if they had their own `update` methods that defined how they move. Also, they could both inherit from a single `Animation` prototype which would contain generic logic for creating animated objects and updating them.
4. Having `segments` and `outerSegments` as dictionaries with the percentages as keys is not helping to produce straightforward code. Consider storing both in a single array `animations`.
5. Consider having a separate function or object that defines segment behaviour when `broke == true`.
6. A different, and ultimately simpler, approach would be to define each stage of the animation -- the first bit where the segments move slowly, the second where they move faster, and the third where they move outside the circle -- as a function that takes the time since the stage begun, and uses that to determine the position and width of the segment. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bvrqh2g/) shows how that could work.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, I was sure @Flambino would pick this one up ;)

**Hint/Lint**

- Some missing semicolons, no big problem
- Some clear copy pasting between `for (var percentage in this.outerSegments)` and `for (var percentage in this.segments)` resulting in declaring `var percentage` and `var segment` twice
- You iterate 3 times over an object with `for( key in object)` without using `object.hasOwnProperty(key)`. You should either

  - Use `object.hasOwnProperty(key)`
  - Use `Object.keys()` to get the keys
  - Convert `segments` and `outerSegments` to arrays ?
    You might be tempted to leave this alone since you are in full control of your script and you wont be modifying the `prototype` of `Object`

**Copy Pastage**

- Definitely the treatment of inner and outer segments could use some re-factoring ( rendering functions, iterating logic etc. )
- This might also be outer/inner segment, but my CPD caught it:

  ```
  this.ctx.arc(
         this.canvas.width / 2,
         this.canvas.height / 2,
         options.radius,
         Helper.toRadians(options.start),
         Helper.toRadians(options.stop),
  ```

**Naming**

- Excellent naming, your code is very easy to follow, and I am no `canvas` expert
- However, so many magical number constants could have used a nice constant name ( 2 , 8 , 60 , 20 etc. etc. )
- Same for the clockwise/counterclockwise parameter in `arc`, those could have been nicely named variables

**Idiomatics**

- I much prefer `function Canvas(canvas) {` over `var Canvas = function(canvas) {`, death to anonymous functions!!
- This:

  ```
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      self.render();
  });
  ```

  could be

  ```
  requestAnimationFrame( this.render );
  ```

  this would be shorter, and you don't need a reference to `self` as it's no longer a closure.

**Commenting**

- There are 0 useful comments in there, and a number of comments that only seem to help the reader in navigating the source

**Paranoia**

- You only call `setPercentage` from 1 place, you check for the upper bound of `100` both prior to calling and inside `setPercentage`, I would consider removing the upper bound check inside setPercentage

**Consistency**

- If functions like `renderPercentage` can take options, then so should `Canvas.prototype.render`

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. Further re-factoring will change the hard-coded numbers into configurable variables. You also mention that `requestAnimationFrame` can be removed of it's closure but also mention that `Canvas.prototype.render` should have option arguments (if I follow correctly). The only way to do this would be to keep the closure. Comments aren't my strong point but I'll be sure to include some on public release. I agree about the `100%` checks but I've had to hack it a bit so it correctly identifies it, without the checks the animation stops at the percentage before `100%`

Comment: So right about the parameter thing! If I were pedantic I would mention `bind` ;)